# Integral of product of normal cdf and pdf

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

What do you think, is there a closed form solution of the following Integral
$\textbf{ }$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}n(x)\, N(b-2y-x)\, dx,$$

where

$N(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x n(z)\, dz\quad$ and $\quad n(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}},\ $ i.e. normal cdf and pdf.

Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: A few equivalent formulas, but no closed form.

Comment: Is numerical integration, in your opinion, the only way to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

The double integral you required to evaluate is $\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{b-2y-x}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}~dz~dx$ .

$\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{b-2y-x}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}~dz~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{b-2y-x}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}~dz~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}~dz~dx+\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_0^{b-2y-x}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}~dz~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}~dx+\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(b-2y-x)^{2n+1}}{2^nn!(2n+1)}dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}~dx+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{a-y}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}~dx-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(x+2y-b)^{2n+1}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!(2n+1)}dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(a-y)^{2n+1}}{2^nn!(2n+1)}-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{a-y}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^nC_k^{2n+1}(2y-b)^{2n-k+1}x^ke^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!(2n+1)}dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(a-y)^{2n+1}}{2^{n+\frac{3}{2}}n!(2n+1)\sqrt\pi}-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^0\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-k+1}x^ke^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!k!(2n-k+1)!}dx-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{a-y}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-k+1}x^ke^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!k!(2n-k+1)!}dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(a-y)^{2n+1}}{2^{n+\frac{3}{2}}n!(2n+1)\sqrt\pi}-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^0\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-2k}x^{2k+1}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!(2k+1)!(2n-2k)!}dx-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^0\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-2k+1}x^{2k}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!(2k)!(2n-2k+1)!}dx-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{a-y}\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-k+1}x^{2m+k}}{2^{m+n}n!k!(2n-k+1)!}dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(a-y)^{2n+1}}{2^{n+\frac{3}{2}}n!(2n+1)\sqrt\pi}+\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-2k}x^{2k+1}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!(2k+1)!(2n-2k)!}dx-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-2k+1}x^{2k}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^nn!(2k)!(2n-2k+1)!}dx-\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-k+1}x^{2m+k+1}}{2^{m+n}n!k!(2n-k+1)!(2m+k+1)}\right]_0^{a-y}$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(a-y)^{2n+1}}{2^{n+\frac{3}{2}}n!(2n+1)\sqrt\pi}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!k!(2y-b)^{2n-2k}}{2^{n-k+1}n!(2k+1)!(2n-2k)!\pi}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-2k+1}}{2^{n+k+1}n!k!(2n-2k+1)!\sqrt\pi}-\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+n}(2n)!(2y-b)^{2n-k+1}(a-y)^{2m+k+1}}{2^{m+n+1}n!k!(2n-k+1)!(2m+k+1)\pi}$

Comment: Is this "a closed form solution"? The formula in the post seems preferable in every sense of the term.

Comment: @Did: It is also consider so call as "a closed form solution", but given that you should not mind about the nested summation form.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Could you expand on it?

Comment: @Did: That means although it cannot be expressable in terms of known special functions, it can still expressable as infinite series form.